# Proving function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

Define $f : [0, 1] → \Bbb R$ by
$f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is rational,$1/(d^{1/2})$
if $x$ is irrational and $x = 0.0 . . . 0d . . . $,
where $d$ is the first nonzero digit in the decimal expansion of $x$. Prove
that $f$ is measurable.

My solution:

{$x: f(x)>1$}$=\phi$, which has measure $0,$

{$x: f(x)<0$}$=\phi$, which has measure $0,$

{$x: 0\leq f(x)\leq 1$}$=[0,1]= (-\infty, 1]\cap [0,\infty)$,

$(-\infty, 1]$ and $[0,\infty)$ both are measurable as Borel sets. Hence the intersection is measurable.

This proves that $f$ is measurable.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: I don't see a proof. You need to show $\{x: f(x)>t\}$ is measurable for all $t$. Also, $\{x: f(x)>0\}=\phi$ is completely false as any irrational gives a positive value for $f$.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write {$x: f(x)<0$}$=\phi$

Comment: So do you suggest I pick $t=1$ and then prove the above cases?

Comment: No, it needs to be measurable for *all* $t$. In particular, pick $t=1/\sqrt{d}$ for $1,2,\cdots,9$ and then the rest will follow.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be the set of irrationals in $[0,1].$ For $k = 1,2,\dots ,9,$ define

$$E_k = E\cap \left [\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \,(k/10^n,(k+1)/10^n)\right ].$$

The sets $E_k$ are clearly measurable, and $E$ is the pairwise disjoint union of them. Note that $f = 1/\sqrt k$ on $E_k.$ Thus

$$f = \sum_{k=1}^{9}(1/\sqrt k)\chi_{E_k}$$

on $[0,1].$ Measurability of $f$ is now easy to check.